# How do I load the same Crystal Report twice?

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

For some reason I can't load this report twice in one program session. I can print it the first time without a problem. The second time I get the error:

```
CrystalDecisions.Shared.CrystalReportsException: Load report failed.
```

Here is my code for this segment.

```
Private Sub Print_Report()
    Using CrystalReport As New ReportDocument
        CrystalReport.Load("Reports\PrintMe.rpt")
        CrystalReport.SetParameterValue("Code", txtCode.Text)
        CrystalReport.SetParameterValue("Control", txtControl.Text)
        CrystalReport.PrintOptions.PrinterName = DefaultPrinterName()
        CrystalReport.PrintToPrinter(1, True, 0, 0)
    End Using
End Sub

Private Function DefaultPrinterName() As String
    Dim psDefault As New System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings
    Try
        DefaultPrinterName = psDefault.PrinterName
    Catch ex As System.Exception
        DefaultPrinterName = ""
    Finally
        psDefault = Nothing
    End Try
End Function
```

All I can think is that the file isn't being let go at the end of the first print. Am I over looking something simple?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issues was caused by using Foxit Reader's PDF Printer. I switched to using Adobe Acrobat and the issue is now gone. I'm only using the PDF Printer for printer tests to save paper. I will be using the Export to Disk for anything PDF related.